# combobox with array id

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, combobox

I want my combobox and checkbox id contains element of array..
Example: "mySelect$i" or "checkid[i]"..
I want to use this to generate different id.
So, it will be like "mySelect1", "mySelect2" or "checkid1", "checkid2".
Help me please.
Here is my following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function run(){
    var cb = document.getElementById("mySelect");
    if(document.getElementById("checkid").checked == true){
        cb.disabled = true;
    }else{
        cb.disabled = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: `"<input type='radio' id='id$i' name='statmk$i' value='$j'" .((check_value)?"checked":"") . "></input>"`

Comment: all the three radio button id, value and name are same how you can differentiate them

Comment: All of your Radio buttons will have the same VALUE

Comment: than assign it inside the ist while loop... $i = 1;

Comment: any suggest, please?

Answer (score 0):

Check Radio Button ID, Name and Value..

It should be unique. otherwise it will treat as all the same.